# Tomcat Port 8080 Can't Be Viewed in Other Network

Tags: tomcat

I have successfully deployed a tomcat project in my webhost... I can view it in my machine but I asked outside my network, they can't view it. They got different error messages. What would be the possible problems?

Comment: Most likely your firewall.  Have you tried asking them to `telnet yourip 8080`?  If so, what happens?  (And what were these "error messages" they received?)

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information here JR Galia, and may be able to get more help if you ask the question on serverfault (as I suspect, since you can view the app locally, that your issue is related to networking, not programming).

What kind of error messages are these other users experiencing? 404? 500 stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling any local firewall and make sure you're listening not only on 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

Answer (score 0):

If you can telnet to the port locally, that probably means your firewall is interfering.  For Windows, check your firewall and add an "exception".  For linux, you're probably using an iptables based solution:

[Linux Firewall Manual](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch14_%3a_Linux_Firewalls_Using_iptables)